# How to generate heat map inside a mat table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, heatmap, angular-material-table

I have a code which displays the temperature details of CPU and GPU in mat table and I want to represent them in the form of a heat map which can be attractive visually.

[image]

My current table

[image: And I want to display]

And I want to display